# ExpandableListView in ViewFlipper display problem?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, viewflipper

After I put my ExpandableListView component in a ViewFlipper element, I got this:

[image]

My layout file is this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!--adding views to ViewFlipper-->
        <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/List01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Flipper Content 0"></ExpandableListView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Flipper Content 1"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Flipper Content 2"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Flipper Content 3"></TextView>
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>....</LinearLayout>
```

Does anybody have an idea why the item rows are just partially in orange?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the widths to 'wrap_content'.
Set them to 'match_parent' instead, that should do the trick.